# How to do versioning while editing a WFST service published using geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I'm trying to edit a WFST service and need to keep different versions for quality checking and acceptance. when we edit a WFST service , it will directly change the db.could anyone please suggest a method ?

Comment: check out geogig http://geogig.org/

Comment: thanks , but i dont need to keep a separate repo , need to access a layer and do some editing , instead of making changes keep an edited version , im thinking of creating a view of a table associated with the layer while editing . And once editing is done , publish a layer using that view with python script . im thinking these kind a work flow

Comment: You will need to develop a custom workflow then